# html5 video: once the video is loaded, a flash is appeared. how to remove it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-video

I am using html5  and while the video is downloading I am using a fallback image in poster attribute. but the problem is once the video is downloaded a flashy screen is showing for a short period of time. how can I remove this, so that the flash will not visible?

```
<video class="bg-video" loop="" muted="" autoplay="" playsinline="" poster="https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/Zs0bsagDzw8/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <source />
</video>
```

live site:

https://nordic.dnscheck.io/

Comment: This is a known issue in some browsers - made worse when displaying the video at a large size. The best workaround I know is to hide the video by default and listen for the [`loadedData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadeddata_event) event before displaying it.

Comment: You mean a black frame?

Comment: @Kaiido, check the video on live link. you will understand. once the fallback image gone, there is a blink/flash is visible before the video starts playing

Comment: That "blink/flash" is black, right?

Comment: Open video in its own [tab](https://nordic.dnscheck.io/nordic.webm) watch/skip to end, when it stops, press play again - there's a "flicker".  As per @Kaiido the issue is that the first frame is black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the black frame, it's in your video so you should edit it out from there.

If you really can't edit that file anymore you can still kind of workaround that by using the [media fragment syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/#media-fragment-syntax) and make your video automatically seek to after that black frame:

```html
<video muted loop autoplay
  poster="https://nordic.dnscheck.io/bilder/poster.webp"
  src="https://nordic.dnscheck.io/nordic.webm#t=0.8"
></video>
```

However beware that the black frame will still be here at the next loop.

Also, while it's not an issue for you since you do autoplay the video, one should note that (currently) setting the seeking time through the media fragment syntax will disable the poster once the video has loaded.

Comment: it didn't work. did you check the live site?

Comment: I did. You didn't edit your video file yet, nor did you apply the "workaround".

Comment: my question was not about the black frame. its about the blinking, I mean when the poster is showing at that time the video is loading. and once the video loads, just before the video screen blinks for a very short period of time. the problem is not in the video cause, If I remove the poster attribute that that blink is not visible.

Comment: But that blink **is** the black frame at the beginning of your media. You don't notice it when you don't have the poster because the transition is more abrupt between the video frame and the previous background. You can try to set the video's background-image to that poster and it will do the same. The poster isn't the issue.

Comment: after applying your suggestion, I am getting this warning:

input: ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.34 -to: 00:00:31.70 -i /home/ashik/Desktop/nordic.webm -c copy /home/ashik/Desktop/trimmed.webm

ouput: Option to: (record or transcode stop time) cannot be applied to input url /home/ashik/Desktop/nordic.wen input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.
Error parsing options for input file /home/ashik/Desktop/nordic.webm.

Comment: For clarity:  "frame" = single picture/segment of the video, not a "border"

Comment: @Kaiido any suggestion?

Comment: No idea. Sounds like there was a typo when you ran that command but I can't see it in your comment. Here this command does work.

Comment: ah.. can you send me that trimmed.webm ? It would be very helpful

Comment: Weird ffmpeg apparently still did prepend a black frame... Had to use HandBrake instead. https://www.dropbox.com/s/64lcmt28xqpnrmk/nordic.webm?dl=0